# consecutive prime gaps and explicit bounds

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I am aware of the theorem that $p_{n+1} - p_n \leq n^{0.535}$ which is true for all sufficiently large numbers due to Baker, but if i want to make the implicit for all sufficiently large number to explicit, is it known that $ p_{n+1}- p_n \leq c_0 n^\alpha $ for all $n \geq 1$ and for small $c_0$, lets say $c_0 \leq 2$ and $\alpha \leq 0.55$ ?

Any ref or known explicit numbers $c_0 ,\alpha $ would be great.

Thanks

Comment: I’m not aware of any explicit versions with exponents anywhere near .55. My understanding is that there is nothing in the method preventing the 2001 Baker-Harman-Pintz 0.525 result from being made fully explicit; it just takes a lot of work that no one has done. It would make a good thesis project.